# Protobuf: Nullable array of values

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

is there a way to model nullable arrays in protobuf?
I initially tried using

```
[...]
repeated google.protobuf.BoolValue values = 1;
[...]
```

but when used inside a gRPC service in C# this (obviously) translates to `bool?[]` instead of `bool[]?`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think empty collections and null are represented the same way in the serialized data. At least I ran into that problem when using protobuf.net. So you might need some workaround, like storing if the collection is empty or null in another field. On the other hand, is the difference relevant? How is null different from an empty array? and is that difference clear to anyone reading the code?

Comment: This is supposed to be more like a QoL thing. Basically you're supposed to provide the JSON structure of what you're trying to read (but I'm not gonna go deeper into that as it's not that important).
So basically, when you're reading you don't need to provide said array instead of just passing an empty array.
When you're writing you pass the values that should be written.

Comment: I think you should describe a bit what you are actually doing. Normally you want to separate input parameters from the result. If you have optional parameters, then just using a repeated field should be fine. I.e. there should be no syntactical difference between null and empty array, and you just need to check that your deserialization library outputs an empty array and not null if the collection is empty.